# Display Welcome Message in v4 Bot Framework Bot (C# + .Net Core Web Application)

Tags: c#, botframework

I had created a bot with v3 (C#) SDK and the welcome message used to work just fine without any sweat. And it still does for me in production. The code is handled in HandleSystemMessage like this -

.. v3 Code additional code removed for clarity...

```
else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
{
// Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
// Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
// Not available in all channels

//Code to show Welcome Message
if (message.MembersAdded.Any(o => o.Id == message.Recipient.Id))
{
var reply = message.CreateReply();
reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
// Create the attachment.
Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
{
ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
Content = AdaptiveCardHelper.GetOptionsCard()
};
reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
}
}
```

The Web Chat version that I use is BotFramework-WebChat-0.11.4, I have done certain customizations in it to implement facebook Like/Unlike feature with comment.

Now I am migrating the bots to v4 SDK (C# + .Net Core Web App), and I am intending to use the same old version of webchat. But I am struggling for two days to get a welcome message displayed in the same web chat while it works well on emulator (given to that two ConversationUpdate) events.

I have tried sending a message as well as an event using the solution provided in this article and tried to catch that in Bot on different async methods OnEventAsync, OnEventActivityAsync, OnMessageActivityAsync.

https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/

V4 Code looks like below:

```
 protected override async Task OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded != null)
            {
                if (turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded.Any(m => m.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient?.Id))
                {
                    //var welcomeCard = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();
                    //var response = CreateResponse(turnContext.Activity, welcomeCard);
                    //await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);

                    await Utility.LogTraceAsync("Inside OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync");

                        var eventActivity = turnContext.Activity.AsConversationUpdateActivity();

                        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(eventActivity.ServiceUrl), Configuration.MicrosoftAppId, Configuration.MicrosoftAppPassword);

                        await Utility.LogTraceAsync("Service URL OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync" + eventActivity.ServiceUrl);

                        await Utility.LogTraceAsync("Recipient ID OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync" + turnContext.Activity.Recipient?.Id);

                        var welcomeCard = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();

                        var reply = ((Activity)eventActivity).CreateReply();
                        reply.Attachments.Add(welcomeCard);

                    //var response = CreateResponse(turnContext.Activity, welcomeCard);
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);// turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);

                        await Utility.LogTraceAsync("OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync Response Returned.");

                    await Utility.LogTraceAsync("Exit OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync");
                }
            }
        }

        protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Utility.LogTraceAsync("Inside OnEventActivityAsync");
            if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event)
            {
                var eventActivity = turnContext.Activity.AsEventActivity();

                await Utility.LogTraceAsync("Event Activity from WebChat matched.");

                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(eventActivity.ServiceUrl), Configuration.MicrosoftAppId, Configuration.MicrosoftAppPassword);

                await Utility.LogTraceAsync("Service URL " + eventActivity.ServiceUrl);

                var welcomeCard = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();

                var reply = ((Activity)eventActivity).CreateReply();
                reply.Attachments.Add(welcomeCard);

                var members = await connector.Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(eventActivity.Conversation.Id.ToString());
                var membernames = "";
                foreach (var member in members) {
                    membernames += member.Name + ",";
                }

                await Utility.LogTraceAsync(membernames);

                await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(reply, cancellationToken);

                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);// turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);

                await Utility.LogTraceAsync("Event Response Returned.");
            }

            await Utility.LogTraceAsync("Exit OnEventActivityAsync");
        }
```

But it does not seem to work at all. I am pulling my hairs out and there is no clue on how to do for .Net Core App. I will be glad to know if someone has solved this problem.

Update -  I have used the JS code on client-side as provided by @tdurnford and at Bot Side had following two methods -

```
//Required to Show Welcome Message on Emulator
protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in membersAdded ?? Array.Empty<ChannelAccount>())
            {
                // Greet anyone that was not the target (recipient) of this message.
                // To learn more about Adaptive Cards, see https://aka.ms/msbot-adaptivecards for more details.
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    Activity reply = ((Activity)turnContext.Activity).CreateReply();
                    AdaptiveCard card = AdaptiveCardHelper.GetWelcomeCard();
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
                    {
                        ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                        Content = card
                    };
                    reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }

//Required to Show Welcome Message on Web Chat
        protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "webchat/join")
            {
                Activity reply = ((Activity)turnContext.Activity).CreateReply();
                AdaptiveCard card = AdaptiveCardHelper.GetWelcomeCard();
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
                {
                    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                    Content = card
                };
                reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
```

With both methods two welcome messages are shown in the chat window -

[Bot Window with two Welcome Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4HM2.png)

Then I've commented the OnEventActivityAsync method in C# and deployed again. Now it shows only one welcome message returned from OnMembersAddedAsync as shown in the window.

[Bot Window with only one Welcome Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV98y.png)

If I comment the following code lines in the webchat code i.e. don't send the post-activity -

```
botConnection.postActivity({
    from: {
        id: 'myUserId',
        name: 'myUserName'
    },
    type: 'event',
    name: 'webchat/join',
    value: {
        locale: 'en-US'
    }
}).subscribe(
    id => console.log("Posted welcome event, assigned ID ", id),
    error => console.log("Error posting activity", error)
);
```

In this case, no welcome message is displayed. @tdurnford, please check if you are able to replicate this behavior.

Although there is another problem here in this way that when a user types a question in the bot, then a welcome message is displayed again.
[Bot window with two welcome messages one on load and another after the first question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBS5V.png)

Comment: Why are you using Web Chat v0.11.4? The newest version of Web Chat is highly customizable  and there is a [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/09.customization-reaction-buttons) that shows how to quickly add Reaction Buttons to messages. I would recommend taking a look at v4 since older versions are no longer supported.

Comment: If you do want to continue using your current version, I will need to get some more information from you since I'm unfamiliar with v0.11.4. Does that version still use the DirectLineJs pacakge? If you could add your Web Chat code, that would be helpful.

Comment: @tdurnford, yes it uses the DirectLineJs package. The catch here is that on a v3 bot it works just fine without raising an extra event or something like that. Here is the source link for that version-  https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/releases/tag/v0.11.4

Comment: @tdurnford, is it possible for you to try this out at your end with a simple Core Bot + Web Chat 0.11.4. I am very much sure you will be able to see the reason for the problem.

Comment: There is a backchannel example in the samples folder of that version @amitc The blog post you referenced is just using the backchannel to send a request to the bot for a welcome message.  How that is handled in the bot has changed from v3 to v4, but the 0.11.4 backchannel client side code is the same.

Comment: @EricDahlvang, Thanks a lot for your response. I checked the samples the folder and found the backchannel example and the client-side code is indeed same. But as you've mentioned handling backchannel in the bot has changed from v3 to v4, thus can you guide me on what code should be written at bot side to handle the incoming event and return the welcome message. And also I have noticed that this additional postActivity request from client side code take a little more time than intial conversations request sent over directline causing subtle delay for the user to see the first message.

Comment: One more thing I found while tracing the code. Following code is being executed inside OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync but nothing sent back from the connectorClient in v4. Can there be something related to this? `ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(eventActivity.ServiceUrl), Configuration.MicrosoftAppId, Configuration.MicrosoftAppPassword);await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);// turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, the channel sends two conversation update events when the conversation is initialized - one for the bot and another for the user. The second one - the event for the user - is intended to trigger the welcome message. Unlike some other channels, Web Chat waits to send the second conversation update event until after the user messages the bot. Evidently, the welcome message won't be sent until after the first message. To workaround this issue, developers can send a back channel welcome event to the bot when the DirectLine connection is established and send a welcome message from the onEventAsync handler instead of onMembersAdded. For more details, take a look at the code snippets below.

**Bot Chat Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/0.11.4/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="display: flex">
      <div style="position: relative; height: 500px; width: 500px"><div id="bot" ></div></div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/0.11.4/botchat.js"></script>

    <script>

      (async function() {

        const res = await fetch('/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
        const { token }  = await res.json();

        var userinfo = {
              id: 'user-id',
              name: 'user name',
              locale: 'es'
          };

        var botConnection = new window.BotChat.DirectLine({ token });

        botConnection.connectionStatus$
          .subscribe(connectionStatus => {
              switch(connectionStatus) {
                  case window.BotChat.ConnectionStatus.Online:
                    botConnection.postActivity({
                        from: { id: 'myUserId', name: 'myUserName' },
                        type: 'event',
                        name: 'webchat/join',
                        value: { locale: 'en-US' }
                    }).subscribe(
                        id => console.log("Posted welcome event, assigned ID ", id),
                        error => console.log("Error posting activity", error)
                    );
                    break;
              }
          });


        BotChat.App({
          botConnection: botConnection,
          user: userinfo,
          bot: { id: 'botid' },
          resize: 'detect'
        }, document.getElementById("bot"));

      })().catch(err => console.log(err));

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Bot Code - C#**

```cs
protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "webchat/join") {
      await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Welcome Message!");
    }
}

protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId != "webchat" && turnContext.Activity.ChannelId != "directline") {

        foreach (var member in membersAdded)
        {
            if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Hi there - {member.Name}. {WelcomeMessage}", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(InfoMessage, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(PatternMessage, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Screen Capture**

[image]

Also note, Web Chat v0.11.4 is referred to as either Bot Chat or Web Chat v3. Sorry I got tripped up on that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @tdrunford, thanks for your response. I used your code above without connection status check as it was returning 0 and not calling post activity. Thus I've used only PostActiity part and verified the webchat/join activity being posted from the client-side and it also reached to OnEventActivityAsync method which I verified from trace logs of code. I also verifed the response of the activity call is returned `{
  "id": "KvCB2ZH26fPII2SQu8lYEK-c|0000000"
}` but unfortunately, the welcome message is not rendered by the webchat. If I post a real question it returns a response and it is rendered.

Comment: Are you sending the welcome message from the `OnEventActivityAsync` handler? This approach should not trigger the `onMembersAddedAsync` handler where welcome messages are usually handled.

Comment: The connection status should switch to online - which I believe is 2 - when the connection to the bot is established. I'm not sure why you would have an issue with that. I'll have to look into that more.

Comment: @turnford, yes, I am sending the message back from OnEventActivityAsync. In fact I have been trying to return an adaptive card with a text message, to mimic how webchat is able to render a normal response after real typed message to bot vs an event activity posted programmatically and a response returned. The main differences I can see after looking into webchat code is that trySendMessageEpic middleware is not invoked from the redux store for programmatic event activity. I am directly looking into js code generated i.e. botchat.js. Instead of connection, I'd request you look at the response.

Comment: @turnford, I tried using the client-side logic from this [link](https://github.com/compulim/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/0cc041356438fddd02c3725ff621eeafbe269663/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event/index.html) and with v4 version of Web Chat and the welcome message is still not displayed on the web chat control.

Comment: Can you add your Web Chat code to your question? I updated my answer to include all of my HTML. I don't believe the event should trigger anything on the Web Chat side - it's just a backchannel activity being sent to the bot.

Comment: @turnford, thanks for adding screenshot it motivated me to look my code line by line. Well, I noticed that in my web chat code `BotChat.App({ --- });` was initialized first and then I was calling `botConnection.PostActivity` without connection check. But I removed my existing code and used yours in place and voila it worked but showed two messages on Web Chat Window. The reason was I had bot OnMembersAddedAsync and OnEventActivityAsync in my bot code. I kept OnMembersAddedAsync to view the welcome message in Emulator. I commented OnEventActivityAsync method & redeployed now get only 1 message.

Comment: This means that ideally just a backchannel activity is required to let both user and bot added to the conversation and then OnMembersAddedAsync can be used to display the welcome message. I want you to ascertain this fact at your end as well. I will update my question with C# bot code and with screenshots. Once you've verified it, please update here so that we can conclude this amazing discussion. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Don't send a welcome message from `onMembersAddedAsyn` if the channel is Web Chat or DirectLine, so that you don't get two welcome messages. I added this to the code snippets in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think a better way to seal it off is to use this code check. 
`if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == "emulator") {
foreach (var member in membersAdded)
    {
        if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
        {
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Hi there - {member.Name}. {WelcomeMessage}", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
...
        }
    } 
}`
I think this post will help everyone with clear indications on how to solve this issue.

Comment: The Bot Service Registration supports multiple channels - Teams, Skype, Facebook Messenger, Twillio, Line, etc. Its easier to check for just Web Chat and DirectLine than all of the other channels. I can certainly change the if statement to check if the channel is not Web Chat or Direct Line instead.

Comment: Sure, it sounds okay. Thanks for your shift responses.

Answer (score 1):

tdurnford's answer didn't work for me. I'm using a new v4 bot (no migration) and embedding iframe into Sharepoint. OnEventActivityAsync just doesn't trigger. I get a conversation update with my bot being a MembersAdded so I did this:

```
    protected override async Task OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await base.OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

        if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == "webchat" && turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded?.FirstOrDefault(m => m?.Name == Configuration["BotName"]) != null)
        {
            await SendWelcomeMessageAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

BotName is "Bot" for local development and the app name for azure deployed apps. SendWelcomeMessage is my own method. Also as above, I added a check in OnMembersAddedAsync:

```
protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == "webchat" || turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == "directline")
            return;

        foreach (var member in membersAdded)
        {
            // Greet anyone that was not the target (recipient) of this message.
            // To learn more about Adaptive Cards, see https://aka.ms/msbot-adaptivecards for more details.
            if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
            {
                await SendWelcomeMessageAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In v4 of the Bot Framework SDK this functionality is handled by making your bot class inherit from the [ActivityHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.activityhandler?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) class then overriding the [OnMembersAddedAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.activityhandler.onmembersaddedasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) method.

How this looks in practice is:

```
...

public class MyBot : ActivityHandler
{
    ...

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                // Greet anyone that was not the target (recipient) of this message.
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    var welcomeMessage = "Hello and welcome!";

                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(welcomeMessage, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

There are examples of how to do this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/03.welcome-user/Bots/WelcomeUserBot.cs#L55), [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Bots/DialogAndWelcomeBot.cs#L23), and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch/Bots/DispatchBot.cs#L38).

You may have to update the version of the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder` package that you are using.

Comment: Matt, Thanks for your response. I have tried this code already and my Bot inherits from ActivityHandler only. The catch is this works only in Emulator but in WebChat control, this code does not work. Have you tried anything that works on WebChat control?

Comment: In webchat the welcome message will not be sent until the user has sent a message, this is a known issue. What you can do is use the back channel functionality to force the bot to send the welcome first. There is an example of how to do this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event/index.html) among with others which you will find if you google the issue. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Matt, but as I said above I am not using the latest web chat control and instead this version BotFramework-WebChat-0.11.4. And whatever things I have tried haven't worked so far after googling and also putting my brain into the problem.

Comment: Is there some reason that you cannot upgrade to the latest version of webchat? tdurnford provided a link to a sample above. Also posting your webchat code would help.