# microsoft bot framework, chatbot loading with blank screen

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot, azure-bot-service

my chatbot is loading with blank screen. When i close the chat and open it again it loads perfect and work fine. i am not sure what could be the reason for this.

I am using Microsoft bot framework v4, and my chatbot is deployed in web.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Sanjeev Gautam

Comment: Can you please show how is this happening, what do you mean "it loads perfect" what does load? It would be very helpful if you can attach a comparison GIF

Answer (score 1):

Unlike emulator, when hosted the Bot will wait for a message from User first. If you want to send a welcome message as soon as bot is active then have a look at solutions here:

[Display Welcome Message in v4 Bot Framework Bot (C# + .Net Core Web Application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863203/display-welcome-message-in-v4-bot-framework-bot-c-net-core-web-application)